# What's the most efficient way to programmatically check if the year is changed

Tags: c++, c++11, time, sniffing

I am trying to capture packets from the NIC and save part of the packet payload as a string.

On part of packet that must be stored is its Log Time known as SysLog. Each packets has a SysLog with the following Format:

```
Nov 01 03 14:50:25 TCP...[other parts of packet Payload]
```

As it can be seen, the packet SysLog has no Year Number. My program must be running all over the year, so I need to add Year Number to the packet SysLog and convert SysLog to epoch time. The final string that I have to store is like this:

```
1478175389-TCP, ….
```

I use the following peace of code to convert Syslog to EpochTime.

```
tm* tm_date = new tm();
Std ::string time = Current_Year;
time += " ";
time += packet.substr(0,18);
strptime(time.c_str(), "%Y %b %d %T", tm_date);
EpochTime = timegm(tm_date);
```

The currentYear  Method:

```
std::string    currentYear() {
    std::stringstream now;
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch());
    size_t modulo = ms.count() % 1000;
    time_t seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(ms).count();
#if HAS_STD_PUT_TIME
#else
    char buffer[25]; // holds "2013-12-01 21:31:42"
    if (strftime(buffer, 25, "%Y", localtime(&seconds))) {
        now << buffer;
    }
#endif // HAS_STD_PUT_TIME
    return now.str();
}
```

The above operations are what i have to do for every packets. The packet rate is 100000-1000000 pps and the above peace of code is very time consuming specially on currentYear(). 
One possible optimization is to remove currentYear() Method and save the 
Year number as a constant value. As said earlier my program must be run all over the year and as you know 2017 is comming. We can not change our binary at 31/12/2016 23:59:00 and also we don’t want to waste our time for calculating Year Number!!

I need a more efficient way to calculate the current year number without  running it for each packet.

Is it possible? What is your suggestion for me?

Comment: have you profiled what exactly takes the most time there? If it is the string conversion I might have an idea but  not sure if it takes much time. Also modulo is in general an expensive operation.

Comment: You can't do this in a foolproof manner if the source timestamps are incomplete.

Comment: I removed your C tag since you're using C++ (C and C++ are different languages), and added C++11 tag since you're using keyword `auto` and `chrono` library

Comment: Can you not do this on the information you get up from your packet capture ? e.g.. if you are using libpcap, you will get a struct with the timestamp of the packet (in a struct timeval), which is trivial to convert to a text representation of your choosing. (If on the other hand you are parsing text output from e.g. tcpdump - you might be better off not doing that and instead use libpcap - or find a way to configure your syslog server to store a proper timestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have obtained the current date and time, based on this it shouldn't be too difficult to calculate what the epoch time will be for  midnight of next January 1st.

After calculating the expected epoch time for when the year rolls around, going forward all you have to do is compare it to the current time, when making a log entry. If it hasn't reached the precalculated Jan 1 midnight time, you know that the year hasn't rolled around yet.

So, you don't need to calculate the year for every packet at all. Just need to check the current time against the precalculated January 1st midnight time, which shouldn't change unless the politicians decide to change your timezone, while all of this is running...

Comment: _"unless the politicians decide to change your timezone, while all of this is running..."_ It's not inconceivable that a leap second may be announced during the year, for the same year. In fact, this is reasonably commonplace. You should update the "epoch" once in a while. (I'm assuming UTC)

Comment: packet rate is 500000 pps in average. how much  the "if" statement you suggested would be checked?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  This would be true only if your timezone is a "right/...." timezone, which counts leap seconds. This is very rare in practice. Ordinary timezones ignore leap seconds, and ntpd slowly paces the system clock, slowing it down or speeding it up over the course of the day, to absorb the leap second. There's been ~30 or so leap seconds added since epoch, and if epoch time were to include leap seconds, the :00-second epoch time would not longer be evenly divisible by 60. But it still is. Unless your TZ is "right/America/New_York", instead of "America/New_York", for example.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: _"Ordinary timezones ignore leap seconds"_ No they don't. If that were true, local timezones would be offsets from UTC plus an offset of 26+ seconds. But they're not. America/New_York is exactly 5 hours off UTC (depending on time of year). You can see your computer clock count up to 23:59:60 at NYE this year :)

Comment: By "ignore" I mean that the day after a leap second has been added/removed is still 86400 seconds after the previous day.

Comment: @m.r226: It doesn't matter how often the `if` statement is checked, it only matters that it is far more efficient than the code you currently use the same number of times.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That'll be true until we get to 86400 leap seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you might consider `currentYear()` returning an `int`  (e.g. 2016), probably with [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html), the `tm_year`  field....  You'll then avoid making C++ strings.

Then, you speak of high packet rate, so you probably have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). You don't explain how it is done (hopefully you use some library à la [libevent](http://libevent.org/), or at least your own loop around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)....), but you might compute the current year only once every tenth of second in that event loop. Or have some other thread computing the current year once in a while (you'll probably need a mutex, or use `std::atomic<int>`  as the type of current year...)

Answer (score 1):

The year is changed for log entries beginning with `Jan`, and only those log entries.

Log entries sometimes come out of order, or carry a timestamp saved during previous processing.

Attaching the year from the PC clock will give bad results, such as

> ```
> 2016 Dec 31 23:59:58    normal
> 2016 Jan 01 00:01:01    printing time placed in packet by remote device, remote clock is running a bit fast
> 2017 Dec 31 23:59:59    printing timestamp saved locally two seconds before logging occurred
> 2017 Jan 01 00:00:03    back to normal
> ```

You *can't* just concatenate the year of local clock with the month...second of the log message.  You have to assign the year that avoids large clock jumps.

Since you're trying to produce Unix time (seconds since epoch) anyway, start by turning the log message time into Julian (seconds since start of year) and test whether the Julian is less than or greater than say 10 million (roughly 4 months).

Answer (score 1):

You can "cache" the string you generate and only change it when the year changes. It may be though just a "little" improvement depending on what operations take the most time.

```
//somewhere
static int currentYear = 0;
static std::string yearStr = ""; 

//in your function
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();   
auto tnow = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
auto lt = localtime(&tnow); //or gmtime depends on your needs.
if(currentYear != lt.tm_year)
{
    yearStr = std::to_string(lt.tm_year + 1900);
    currentYear = t.tm_year;
}

return yearStr;
```

I am not sure if static has any negative/positive aspects on the performance of reading the string or a member variable may be better here due to cache locality. You have to test this.

If you use this in multiple threads you have to use a mutex here which probably will reduce performance though (again you have to measure this).